# Port works properly in local network but shows as closed in port scanners for remote access

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding, plex

I am setting up plex server in my laptop which is always connected to network in my home. I was able to install and activate all the features in plex. I am able to access the plex sever in local network through port 32400. Plex have a feature to access it remotely. I added an inbound and outbound rule for my port (32400) and attached the process. Then I added a port forwarding rule in my router(I am using a netgear R6120 router. I am using 32400 as bot external and internal port). I made my laptop IP static using DHCP reservations in my router.

Still doing all these procedures, am not able access it through my public IP remotely. When I checked for open ports in https://www.canyouseeme.org/ it says that it is not open. I changed my IP reservations, changed the external port (I can't change internal port. It is fixed). I tried disabling firewall in my computer. I disabled UPnP in my router. I tried all options that I am aware of. But not able to make it remote accessible. Please help me if I am doing it wrong or I missed anything
Please find the snapshots below

[DHCP Reservation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUJym.png)

[Inbound rule in firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDBTh.png)

[Outbound rule in firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zihVX.png)

[Port forwarding rule in router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyxC7.png)

Comment: Are you sure your public IP address allows incoming connections in the first place? Many ISPs today use [carrier grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT), and this setup prevents incomcing port connections (your ISP would need to add a "port forwarding rule", but usually they don't - instead you'll have to pay for a business plan with a dedicated static IP address).

Answer (score 0):

If you log in to your Plex server and on the left side of the Home screen select "**Settings**" that takes you to your Server settings. Look on the left for "**Remote Access**" and click on it. In the top right of that page you'll see a gray button that says "**Show Advanced**" click on that. You can now see where to specify the port you want the server to use.

You also shouldn't need to specify outbound rules. Those are usually only used to block traffic going out of your computer really. When a client is trying to access your Plex server they won't be doing it on a client port of 32400. Clients use dynamic ports when sending requests to a server, and these dynamic ports are selected at the time of the connection request. So putting an outbound firewall rule of 32400 on your Plex Server machine will prevent Plex from communicating properly with clients on their dynamic ports.

Here's what my connection looks like to my Plex server:

```
TCP    192.168.10.99:51528    192.168.10.25:32400    ESTABLISHED    
TCP    192.168.10.99:51530    192.168.10.25:32400    ESTABLISHED
```

If you open a Command Prompt on your client machine and type in "**netstat -an**" you'll see a list of TCP & UDP connections and the ports those connections are using in both your local system and the remote systems you're connected to.

In my example my PC's IP ends in .99, my Plex Server's IP ends in .25. My PC opens a connection to the Plex server on port 32400, but has dynamic client ports of 51528 & 51530. Those two port numbers are dynamic and randomly chosen at the time of connection. When my PC sends requests to the Plex server it does so on port 32400, and when Plex responds to my requests it does so on ports 51528 & 51530.

Try disabling the Outbound rules on your firewall and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi Brian, 
Thanks for the comment. But I am able to access my plex server inside my home network. I am facing issue when I try to access it outside my home network like when am travelling.